# Не получается сделать градиент

Tags: spritekit, xcode, objective-c, ios7

Я пишу следующий код:

```
CIFilter *Filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIRadialGradient"];

CIColor *startColor = [CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
CIColor *endColor = [CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
CIVector *startVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) Y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)];
NSNumber *radius1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
NSNumber *radius2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1000];
[Filter setValue:startVector forKey:@"inputCenter"];
[Filter setValue:radius1 forKey:@"inputRadius0"];
[Filter setValue:radius2 forKey:@"inputRadius1"];
[Filter setValue:startColor forKey:@"inputColor0"];
[Filter setValue:endColor forKey:@"inputColor1"];

SKEffectNode *effectNode = [SKEffectNode node];
effectNode.filter = Filter;
effectNode.shouldEnableEffects = YES;

[self addChild:effectNode];
```

Но на экране ничего не происходит. Я использую Sprite Kit.

Comment: откуда вы взяли это решение?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19258513/3578258

Comment: Дак ониж говорят что это грябля больше не работает: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19255175/887325
Matt предлогает использовать текстуру с градиентом. И мне тоже кажется это правильней.

Answer (score 1):

А это пробовали (градиент на вьюхе) [link text](https://coderwall.com/p/pv_g3a) и [link text](http://snipplr.com/view/43691/)